# How to check sql database for items of a paragraph exploded via spaces and replace them in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, replace, explode

Basically, The outcome I am looking for is how Wikipedia has text with links all though there text to other wikipedia pages.
I have a database full of definitions, and I have a paragraph full of text that I want to be exploded by spaces, check a sql table for existence of all words and replace the ones that do exist with links to.
Please help.
What I have so far is this(But it doesn't seem to work):

```
$def = $row['def'];(This is just the paragraph)
$checks = explode(' ', $def);

foreach($checks as $key => $check) {
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = '$check'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$find = $row['word'];
$new = "text";

$final = str_replace($find, $new, $checks);

print_r($final);
```

Comment: So...what is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I think that you may suffer from one of the quirks of using foreach, i.e. the `$checks` you do replace on inside the `foreach` is not the same as the `$checks` outside.

Try this.

```
$def = $row['def']; //This is just the paragraph
$checks = explode(' ', $def);

for ($i=0; $i<count($checks); $i++) 
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = '{$checks[$i]}'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
        //$checks[$i] = "text"; //according to your original example
        $checks[$i] = "<a href=\"{$row['url']}\">{$row['word']}</a>"; //something like this, assuming you have a column 'url' in the DB with the link you want to refer to
    }
}

$final = implode(' ', $checks);

print_r($final);
```

Not that this is very efficient, but I think it should work.

Comment: Hey, this works perfect, except now the words in the paragraph are replaced with text. So what should I replace 'text' as the real word but as a link. This is what I have: $ checks [$I] = '<a href="">' . $checks . '</a>'

Comment: I assume you get your replacement from the database so something like `$checks[$i] = "<a href=\"{$row['url']}\">{$row['word']}</a>";` inside the while (depending on what your fields are called)

Comment: @user1919552 If you are happy with the answer, please mark it as accepted, if you still have questions, let me know